# MSBuild - MsBuildExtensionPack starting windows service with delay

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildextensionpack

I am using MSBuild task to start a windows service. I am using following code:

```
MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Start" ServiceName="AppServices"  ContinueOnError='false'/>
```

If I start the service I am getting following error:

```
Start Service failed with return code '[7] ServiceRequestTimeout'
```

Is there any setting or option to tell MSBuild to start service after waiting for a minute or two. Or Is there any way to introduce delay before calling this task within MSBuild?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to tell the actually WindowsService task to delay the command.  You can try putting this before your call though though:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.Thread TaskAction="Sleep" Timeout="1000"/>
```

This will put the executing thread to sleep for the timeout specified (in milliseconds).